# Unity animation resproduces twice on Start

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have a little problem. When loading a scene, in the Start method of my animations script I call the animation "Chestdrop". For some reason this animation plays twice.
The only way to avoid this is to call the method through an Invoke. It doesn't always work though.
Is there a better way to prevent the animation from playing twice?

```
private void Start()
    {
        Invoke(nameof(EnableChest), 0.7f);
    }

private void EnableChest()
    {
       anim.SetTrigger("Activate");
    }
```

Comment: Does the `EnableChest` method get called twice as well? Check with `Debug.Log`

Comment: Triggers are notoriously unpredictable.  Before you `SetTrigger` call `ResetTrigger` right before it.  Not sure if that will help but it's clean.